# How can I make salt-api return more useful data?

Tags: saltstack, json, yaml

```
salt-master: 2016.11.5 (Carbon)
salt-api: 2016.11.5 (Carbon)
salt-minion 2016.11.5 (Carbon)
cherrypy: 10.2.2
```

After setting up salt-api using [this tutorial](http://bencane.com/2014/07/17/integrating-saltstack-with-other-services-via-salt-api/) I've been able to successfully use the API via curl.  For example, I can move files.  However, salt-api seems to return `{"success": true}` as long as some command actually went out to the minion.

Is there a way to get any of the output from the instructions sent to the minion (like, in json or any other format as long as it's useful data)?  For example, when I try to move a file, if the file doesn't exist, salt-api just silently fails and returns `{"success": true}`.  Is there a way to get the output to tell me whether the actual instructions passed or failed?

I was able to find [salt.output.json_out](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/output/all/salt.output.json_out.html#module-salt.output.json_out), which seems to only change the output  of `{"success": true}` to another format....which isn't useful to me.  Is there some documentation I haven't found that can help me return something other than `{"success": true}`?

---

**EDIT**

To clarify, my end goal is to have a program in C# that can make calls to the salt-api, and have it return whether or not the command on the minion was successful.

I know from the output of `salt-master -l debug` that a `retcode` with an actual boolean value exists, but I have no idea how to reach it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial that I was using in the question is a tutorial for setting up salt-api with webhooks.  Which is a fire and forget method.  It turns out that all of the data I wanted is sent back by default with just the standard salt-api configuration found [here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/netapi/all/salt.netapi.rest_cherrypy.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to implement your client in Java, you can find some API clients and examples [here](https://github.com/SUSE/salt-netapi-client) which must be **useful**.

I have only used this API to fetch the minion's grains. I have been working on SaltStack over a month and it's really amazing.